# Cordova File plugin never becomes ready in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a dead simple Cordova app with a single plugin: org.apache.cordova.file.

When I emulate the app in an android emulator, the `deviceready` event is never fired, and I get this as an output:

```
D/CordovaLog( 1841): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1154 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
D/CordovaLog( 1841): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
```

Some additional information:

```
cordova --version
3.5.0-0.2.4

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55

java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src='cordova.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        console.log("Ready");
    }, false);

}());
```

Is the Cordova File plugin broken? Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.

What worked for me was using a different version of the File plugin found here:
https://github.com/onflapp/cordova-plugin-file

Related topic: [Android - Cordova 3.5.0 deviceready not firing after installing media plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470166/android-cordova-3-5-0-deviceready-not-firing-after-installing-media-plugin)

Comment: I believe the issue has been fixed with Apache's repository as well. I'm not running into the issue if I install the file plugin from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.

Comment: This issue is happening to me randomly on android. If I keep calling window.location.reload() sometimes it fails to trigger deviceready event. I am using file@1.3.2 and already tried file@1.1.0 with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue Vitor, often window.location.reload does the same in my app. Did you find a solution?

Comment: The same issue. After updating my cordova from 3.3.0 to 3.6.4 and updating all plugins it stopped firing deviceReady on some devices.

Comment: @DmitryIsakov the solution from related topic helped me. "deviceReady" event was not fired on iPhone due to the absence of CDVFile.m in Compiled Source section of Xcode. (This is one-year late comment, but I hope it would help others struggling with the same issue)

Answer (score 6):

Try installing the 1.1.0 version of the file plugin. Updating to 1.2.0 was a bad idea.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file@1.1.0
```

This made the job for me on Android (and on iOS I stopped having other exotic problems).

Comment: FYI: As version 1.3.0 has been released, I've tried it and now it works fine

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. After trudging through a day of Android Studio, Eclipse, and CLI agony I think this was the final thing I had to resolve to get my app building via Eclipse again. Thank you @ledfusion!

Comment: FWIW - I was using the 1.3.1dev and I had to go back to 1.1.0

Comment: I changed file plugin version to 1.1.0 but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reverting to plugin version 7.0.0, then updating to 8.0.1 again normally.

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to include cordova plugin before closing of body tag , so that cordova gets loaded properly before body loading completes.


<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src='cordova.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```