# Android - Cordova 3.5.0 deviceready not firing after installing media plugin

Tags: android, cordova

This is interesting and weird issue.

First I created Cordova project `locally`. I'm not using `Bd`.
using

`cordova create test com.test.project.story "Test"`

Which worked successfully!

Then I added `android` platform, using

`cordova platform add android`

Worked successfully.

Then I built the project using

`cordova build`

Worked, again.

I opened the project from Eclipse and ran it on emulator.
Worked properly.

Then I thought of adding some plugins in my project using

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

Removed the android platform and added the platform again. Then built and ran the project on emulator.

The screen was stuck on `Connecting to device` forever.

I rechecked if I was using the correct `cordova.js` for android platform. 
It is correct, and it says

```
// Platform: android
// 3.5.0
```

Checked ADB log and there are a lot of suspicious things going on.

```
D/CordovaWebViewClient( 1581): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/CordovaActivity( 1581): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
D/CordovaActivity( 1581): onMessage(spinner,stop)
D/TilesManager( 1581): new EGLContext from framework: 2a1a2a10 
D/GLWebViewState( 1581): Reinit shader
D/dalvikvm(  270): GC_CONCURRENT freed 322K, 46% free 9831K/17991K, paused 813ms+21ms, total 2252ms
D/dalvikvm(  270): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 906ms
D/GLWebViewState( 1581): Reinit transferQueue
W/ApplicationContext( 1581): Unable to create external files directory
D/        ( 1581): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x4a5f8558, tid 1605
E/PluginManager( 1581): Uncaught exception from plugin
E/PluginManager( 1581): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.requestAllPaths(FileUtils.java:866)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.execute(FileUtils.java:348)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:242)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:227)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:655)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/PluginManager( 1581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/dalvikvm(  270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 593K, 48% free 9509K/17991K, paused 275ms, total 280ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  270): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.559MB for 1286224-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 41% free 10763K/17991K, paused 182ms, total 186ms
D/dalvikvm(  270): GC_CONCURRENT freed 61K, 38% free 11284K/17991K, paused 41ms+11ms, total 304ms
D/CordovaActivity( 1581): onMessage(spinner,stop)
D/dalvikvm(  270): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2676K, 43% free 10293K/17991K, paused 16ms+29ms, total 130ms
D/CordovaLog( 1581): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1154 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
I/Web Console( 1581): deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1154
D/CordovaLog( 1581): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
I/Web Console( 1581): Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1147
E/ThrottleService(  149): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
D/dalvikvm(  251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 9% free 6556K/7175K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 67ms
D/dalvikvm(  251): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 9% free 6556K/7175K, paused 6ms+13ms, total 62ms
I/EventLogService(  240): Aggregate from 1403981475023 (log), 1403981475023 (data)
E/ThrottleService(  149): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What's going on here?

UPDATE:

Works fine on iOS.

Comment: 1) you didn't need to remove and re-install the platform. 2) try removing and re-installing those plugins again. (Just a suggestion, don't know will work or not)

Comment: Didn't work, thanks anyway though :)

Comment: Same issue, but I just have the file plugin, no media.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.

What worked for me was using a different version of the File plugin found here:
https://github.com/onflapp/cordova-plugin-file

Related topic: [Cordova File plugin never becomes ready in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438087/cordova-file-plugin-never-becomes-ready-in-android)

Comment: Thank you! Worked! I removed the file plugin and installed the older one `org.apache.cordova.file@1.1.0`

Comment: I have the same problem with Cordova CLI 5.1.1. It works fine on iOS, but not on Android. I only use the InAppBrowser plugin. If I remove the InAppBrowser plugin, deviceready is fired on Android as well. I work with Intel XDK / Cordova for 6 months meanwhile and I experienced that a lot of things are still in its infancy there. Intel XDK might look faster and easier at the first glare, but you will need more time later to find the bugs on Intel XDK. The Intel XDK IDE will not verify if its suggested plugins are compatible with the used Cordova Version. Will try VS+Xamarin next time.

Answer (score 6):

for me it got solved by adding cordova.js in index.html( though its not required in ripple)

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same and resolved using **apache official** dev build File plugin:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/

Funny enough cordova release 1.3.1-dev is more stable then official release 1.2.0 ...

Comment: So because you found one bug that's in the 1.2.0 version but not in the whole 1.3.1-dev version, you know about the whole stability of both versions.

Comment: eh eh MrFox , I wrote that comment after adopting it for an app with no observable side-effect. So for my use case the 1.3.1-dev proved to be more stable than 1.2.0.
All in all this is not so strange since some releases are more focused on stability (remove bugs from previous releases) and some other on adding features (at the price of adding bugs).
The only contribution that I can give is my experience and in my experience this was quite a big bug !

Comment: That would have been fine. But you stated a fact that the dev release is in fact more stable than the official release. I agree you cannot conclude that from your own limited personal experience. So then don't.

Answer (score 2):

By now a [newer version of the file plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/08/11/plugins-release.html) has been released. You should no longer experience the issue with the updated version (and there is thus no longer a need to downgrade).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. deviceReady event was not firing (ionic app on android). Worked after I removed the file plugin v1.2 and then added v1.1 instead.