# Cordova Android app Error: Failed to mkdirat & device ready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Cordova app which was working fine on all android devices, I kept without work for 2 months, then I tried to run on it Samsung Galaxy S3 and S4 but it gives the errors below which start with : `"Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system"` and end with `"device ready has not fired after 5 seconds"`. What is weird is that the app is working on other types of Samsung like Galaxy Win, also works on LG G2.

**P.S:**

1. The error below was captured using `adb logcat` in a .bat file
2. I am using File PLugin and I tried to downgrade the version as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470166/android-cordova-3-5-0-deviceready-not-firing-after-installing-media-plugin)
3. also I [tried to remove](http://christian.fei.ninja/Solution-to-PhoneGap-issue-device-ready-has-not-fired-after-5-seconds) the platform and add it back but also not working
4. I am on Cordova Version: 3.5

**Update:**

5. I forgot to mention that I don't have an sdcard

   ```
   [ 12-20 11:29:53.686   275:  537 E/cutils   ]

   Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.686   275:  537 W/Vold     ]

   Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.696   300: 1323 E/qdmemalloc ]

   heap_msk=40000000 flags=1





   [ 12-20 11:29:53.696 27315:27374 W/ContextImpl ]

   Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.site.myapp/files



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.696   275:  537 E/cutils   ]

   Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.696 27315:27374 W/ContextImpl ]

   Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.site.myapp/files



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.696   275:  537 W/Vold     ]

   Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.706   275:  537 E/cutils   ]

   Failed to mkdirat(/storage/extSdCard/Android): Read-only file system



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.706 27315:27374 W/ContextImpl ]

   Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.site.myapp/cache



   [ 12-20 11:29:53.706   275:  537 W/Vold     ]

   Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.146  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   onReceive: android.net.wifi.RSSI_CHANGED



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.146  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   onReceive() - RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION, WIFI_STATE, NETWORK_STATE



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   notifyRssiChange. suppState=COMPLETED, netState=CONNECTED, mWifiFit=CONNECTED_ROVE_IN, connected: true, original: -68, new: -60



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   calculateRssi. -60



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   processConnectivity. type: 1, connected: true, mRegistered: false, mobile_original: NO_MOBILE, wifi_original: CONNECTED_ROVE_IN, mobile_change: NO_MOBILE, wifi_change: CONNECTED_ROVE_IN



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   processRegCheck. needtoregister: true, mRegistered: false, type: 1, mRtype: 0, Mobile: NO_MOBILE, Wifi: CONNECTED_ROVE_IN, pauseims: DEFAULT, mAtomicNeedDereg.get(): false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mAtomicDereg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mRegistered=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mAtomicReg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   destroyService. false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.157  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.177  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger ]

   checkOverflow(360), More:true, Req:true Child:8



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.187  1588: 1588 E/IPPhoneSettings ]

   getString(GBA_INIT) = 0



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.197  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mAtomicDereg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.197  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mRegistered=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.197  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mServerNotify=NONE



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.197  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mBlockReg.get()=true



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.197  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mReadImpuCount=0



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.957  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.957  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:54.957  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger ]

   checkOverflow(360), More:true, Req:true Child:8



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.127  2044: 2044 W/Settings ]

   Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   onSignalStrengthsChanged



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   processRegCheck. needtoregister: true, mRegistered: false, type: 1, mRtype: 0, Mobile: NO_MOBILE, Wifi: CONNECTED_ROVE_IN, pauseims: DEFAULT, mAtomicNeedDereg.get(): false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mAtomicDereg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mRegistered=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 14 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 gsm|lte 0x5 level=5



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceUnregistration: Abort: mAtomicReg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   destroyService. false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.378  1588: 1588 E/IPPhoneSettings ]

   getString(GBA_INIT) = 0



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.388  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mAtomicDereg.get()=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.388  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mRegistered=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.388  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mServerNotify=NONE



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.388  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mBlockReg.get()=true



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.388  1588: 1588 D/IPPolicy ]

   doIPServiceRegistration: Abort: mReadImpuCount=0



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788  1158: 1158 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor ]

   received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788   825:  825 I/Tethering ]

   BATTERY_CHANGED, level = 8lowBatteryThreshold = 15



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788   825:22548 D/BatteryService ]

   level:8, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3713, temperature: 251, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303669, invalid charger:0, online:4, current avg:460, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788   825:  825 D/BatteryService ]

   Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788  1924: 1924 D/SViewCoverView ]

   BroadcastReceiver onReceive() : action : android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788  1924: 1924 D/SViewCoverView ]

   level :8 plugged : 2



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.788   825:  825 D/UiModeManager ]

   mCoverManager.getCoverState() : true



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor ]

   handleBatteryUpdate



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/CMASMessage ]

   [update] mShowingCMASText is false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/CMASMessage ]

   CMASIcon was GONE : 



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/CMASMessage ]

   [update] mShowingCMASText is false



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/CMASMessage ]

   CMASIcon was GONE : 



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar ]

    mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.798  1158: 1158 D/BatteryMeterView ]

   ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:8 status:2 health:2



   [ 12-20 11:29:55.808  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger ]

   checkOverflow(360), More:true, Req:true Child:8



   [ 12-20 11:29:57.970  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)



   [ 12-20 11:29:57.970  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController ]

   refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false



   [ 12-20 11:29:57.980  1158: 1158 D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger ]

   checkOverflow(360), More:true, Req:true Child:8



   [ 12-20 11:29:58.411 27315:27315 D/CordovaLog ]

   file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1154 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.



   [ 12-20 11:29:58.411 27315:27315 I/chromium ]

   [INFO:CONSOLE(1154)] "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1154)





   [ 12-20 11:29:58.411 27315:27315 D/CordovaLog ]

   file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded



   [ 12-20 11:29:58.411 27315:27315 I/chromium ]

   [INFO:CONSOLE(1147)] "Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (1147)
   ```

Any help please

Comment: How about read/write external storage permission when build application?

Comment: @MrNeo Also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just remove the device plugin and add it again, I know it doesn't make any sense but it works now.

```
cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
```

Then add it back:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

I hope that helps someone one day.