# Upgrade Cordova Version of an iOS app

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

How can I transfer a Cordova iOS app from one PC to other? The app is made in some other version of Cordova and I want to upgrade its Cordova version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

- In new PC, install the latest version of cordova using `npm install -g cordova` command
- In new PC, create a new cordova project using 
  `cordova create PROJECT_NAME command` 
  in desired location using terminal
- Now navigate to the newly create project folder, copy the contents of
  `WWW` folder and `config.xml` file from Old project in Old PC and replace
  the same in newly created project folder.
- In terminal, navigate to project root directory and install the
  required plugins in new project using `cordova plugin add PLUGIN_NAME`
  command
- After installing required plugins, add the iOS platform to the
  project using `cordova platform add ios` command
- Now build the project using `cordova build ios` command

You are good to go now. But you gotta test your project once thoroughly as some plugin may not works as expected with latest cordova version.

Comment: I am getting stuck at the splash screen and getting the following errors:-
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.           cordova.js:1112 
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady              cordova.js:1112 
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady       cordova.js:1112 
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady   cordova.js:1112

Comment: @Utkarsh Did you reinstalled the plugins properly? Also create platform was successful?

Comment: yes.. the plugins are reinstalled properly and create platform was also successful.. build is also succesfull in xcode except the errors

Comment: @UtkarshChauhan if build is successful, whats the actual issue?

Comment: The app is not moving forward from the splash screen and I am getting these errors when I run the app in the browser.

Comment: @UtkarshChauhan you may also have to check this link if you are using file plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470166/android-cordova-3-5-0-deviceready-not-firing-after-installing-media-plugin

Comment: I was having a similar issue where splash would show, and i would get the 2 loading dots continuously... i finally saw there was an error being thrown in a .js file in the app...corrected the issue (which was in the Sencha.js file) which was a simple syntax error where brackets were not closed properly and app worked perfectly after that...so check all your logs and see if anything is being thrown if you have this issue

Answer (score 0):

With the newer versions of Cordova this process has been made much easier. The `config.xml` can now hold entries which specify the plugins and platforms your app will run. Look at this example. You can add these entries to your `config.xml`:

```
<engine name="android" spec="~5.1.1" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.1.0" />
<engine name="browser" spec="~4.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.1.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.0" />
```

When you run `cordova platform prepare ios`, if not already created, Cordova will fetch the missing platforms and plugins for you. This a good way to start building your app if not already started.

Comment: I am getting stuck at the splash screen and getting the following errors:- deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:1112

Comment: Sounds like something is misconfigured with Cordova. Verify you have a script reference in your `index.html` like this: `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`. Also make sure you're correctly listening for the `deviceready` event and calling any of your plugin code after that event has fired.

Answer (score -1):

you can copy project folder one to another. if you have different version you can upgrade. if you have upgraded cordova. type in terminal project's folder  **cordova platform update ios** and **cordova platform update android**  if you dont before this : **sudo npm update -g cordova**

Comment: I am getting stuck at the splash screen and getting the following errors:- deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady cordova.js:1112 Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady cordova.js:1112

Comment: cordova platform remove ios , cordova platform remove android  and add again platform.

Comment: and which plugins do you use ? maybe these are updated. its not compatible with your cordova version.

Comment: I have installed the latest plugins

Comment: No. I have two meta tags. One below head tag and one below title tag. They are as follows:-
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
and
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 " />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113293/discussion-between-utkarsh-chauhan-and-nazir-dogan).

Comment: moving your code to a whole new project is a bit of an extreme time consuming solution. Simply removing the platform and adding it back again fixed this issue for me. Thanks @NazırDogan