# How to upgrade a cordova app and plugins

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have a Cordova (v5.2) app that I run on iOS (platform v3.9.1) and Android (platform v5.0). Is it best to upgrade Cordova from the command prompt, and then manually look for plugin updates, or should I look for plugin updates first then update Cordova? Also, I have recently upgraded from XCode 7.2 to XCode 8 and it is asking me to make changes to recommend project settings, this appears to break thinks. Should I allow XCode to make changes to the project, or should I upgrade Cordova first? I'm looking for a workflow and best way to manage these updates. Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would upgrade your Cordova platform first. The main version that I pay attention to is the cordova platform version. So in your case `cordova-ios@3.9.1` and `cordova-android@5.0.0`. These packages are what control the cordova lib that gets injected into your native project. They also determine which version of Xcode you can use.

The `cordova-cli` pins certain platform versions by default when you run `cordova platform add <platform_name>`. I usually stick with the most stable release of `cordova-cli` for my needs and then add specific platforms (usually the latest) manually. `cordova platform add ios@lateset`.

Any partiular reason you're `cordova@5.2`, `cordova-ios@3.9.1` , and `cordova-android@5.0.0`?

Comment: That is just what I started with and haven't upgraded in a while. However, I followed updating cordova itself first to 6.4, and then ran platform update for iOS to 4.3.1, tried to do a build and got an error, after updating a couple plugins It looks like I'm back in business, thank you for this post the order of operations basically was what I was looking for so I consider this my answer, thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Infact you can also create a new project after cordova update and add the respective platforms and plugins so that the existing working project will be intact for reference.

If you wanna follow this approach then check out this following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498870/upgrade-cordova-version-of-an-ios-app/37499610#37499610). Even that post is related to porting cordova app from one PC to other, the steps still holds good even in this case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade Cordova first (it's better if you install it globally with `npm install -g cordova` ).
After that, to update all of your plugins, you just have to remove them and readd them to your project, they will automatically be updated to be compatible with the last Cordova version.

Answer (score 0):

cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@5.X.X

If you use the above method, be aware that any changes you made to the android platform folder will be lost (editing the contents of this folder is discouraged).

Alternatively, you may attempt to use the platform update script. For non-CLI projects, run:

bin/update path/to/project

For CLI projects:

Update the cordova CLI version. See The Command-Line Interface.

Run cordova platform update android@5.0.0 in your existing projects.